# Seo and sliders on onepage layout

Tags: jquery, search, seo, slider

Hi guys
I'm working on a project with a one page layout. The content is a slider, with information. If people search for something, on Google, that is on slide 4 ex., how can i then display the current slide, when the user enters the site...?

Thank you in advance... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think google announced in a press release that they are supporting hashtags in URLs... Therefore you could use a site-control based on hashes in the URL, e.g. http://foo.com/#bar

On loading your site you can read that hash and control your site according to it...

Comment: I found this:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/perma.html#2 ... But it only displays what slide you're on - you can't link to a specific slide.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is described by Maximilian Ehlers ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837316/seo-and-sliders-on-onepage-layout/4837408#4837408))

The other way is more complicated.
You can use **mod_rewrite** if you're using Apache web server.
You will need to add rewrite rules to your **.htaccess** file.
For example,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /index.php?slide=about [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /index.php?slide=contact [NC,L]
```

Then in your script (index.php) you will get the parameter from URL and set the active slide depending on the value. 
You can pass the parameters value to JavaScript and set an appropriate slide to active there. Or you define the new CSS class for your active slide. 
For example,

```
<div class="slide">content here</div>
<div class="slide active_slide">active slide content here</div>
```

It mostly depends on your script for sliding content and how you can manually set the active slide with it.